# How to restore data from a damaged HDD?

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery, hardware-failure

I have dropped my laptop accidentally. It had Windows and Linux installed along with GRUB, with Windows located at the beginning of the hard drive and Linux near the end.

After that I couldn't boot to the Windows partition, but everything was ok with Linux. So I booted to Ubuntu and made a copy of some important files with[TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) utility. I have easily copied all important informationt to the ext4 partition... on the same hard drive. (Meh, what a stupid thing I have done :( )

Furthemore, I tried to "repair" my HDD with [HDD Regenerator](http://www.dposoft.net/#b_hddhid) which is said to repair bad blocks on the HDD. And as result, it looks like some continious part of the HDD's surface was damaged, and what is the worst is that beginning of the Windows NTFS partition was damaged too. It was possible to locate and access this partition(via TestDisk) before I used "HDD Regenerator". After the "HDD Regenerator" I can't boot to the Linux, as well as I can't access it via TestDisk. It can locate it, but can't list files of this partition(I get something like "this file system is damaged") even via TestDisk. NTFS partition of Windows is not even discoverable by TestDisk. Looks like its beginning was located in the block that was damaged and furthermore "recovered" by HDD Regenerator.

When I scanned this HDD with TestDisk last time, I got ~6000 "Current Pending Sector Count" in S.M.A.R.T last time. Also I can see Windows system partition(100MB), Windows backup partition(16gb), can't see the main Windows 400-GB partition which should follow these two ones and can see two linux(ext4 and swap) partitions, ext4 is not accessible.

Is it a dead end if TestDisk cannot list files in the Linux partition? All I need now is to access at least one of the partitions I have lost(NTFS one with Windows or ext4 with Ubuntu) and to copy ~10 MB of data to an another hard drive. What should I do in order to save this vital 10 MB's?

Comment: To late now, of course, but as soon as you suspect a drive of being damage, you get your data off and bin it. 25 years ago I'd get a few bad blocks from month to month, but the drive kept on going, but these modern hi-tech tend not to degrade so gracefully.

Comment: I don't think for a minute that this might work, but you could try a linux live CD, but if TestDisk can't see the partition, I doubt you'll have any success. The nuclear option is to send to a specialist drive recovery company, who can recover stuff that we wouldn't but there would be a heavy premium for this type of service. Final advice - every time you use this disk, you increase the likelihood of further regression